# Convergence of doubly infinite improper integral for odd functions.

Tags: improper-integrals

I was working on this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}$$

Calculations shows that the limits DNE, and therefore the integral diverge. I used Mathematica and found the same result.

But, the integrand is an odd functions, therefore:

$$\forall c \in \Bbb R : \int_{-c}^{+c} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2} = 0 $$

So why don't we just say that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{c\to\infty} \int_{-c}^{+c} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}=0$$
 And the same for any other odd functions?

Comment: what you are looking for is this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: In a nutshell, because it's equivalent to saying that $-\infty +\infty =0$, which isn't true.

Comment: in order to show that an improper integral is equal to its cauchy principal value, you should first prove that it's convergent.It's not true in contrary. convergence is the sufficient condition but not the necessary condition

Comment: My answer below shows that $\displaystyle \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle \int}{\displaystyle \int}} \lim_{c\to\infty} \int_{-c}^{2c} \dfrac{x\,dx}{1+x^2} = \dfrac 1 2 \log 4$. I don't know why people answer things like this without mentioning things like that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Well, I didn't read before about CPV so I read today and didn't get enough info. about it.

What I found is CPV is a method used to evaluate improper integrals when it cannot be evaluated in regular way. So why can't we use CPV in this integral ?

Comment: @MohamedMostafa : One _can_ use CPV here, but it's not the whole story.  The integral can take different values if the bounds approach infinity differently.  That can happen because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}\right| = \infty$.  If the integral of the absolute value had been finite, then the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ would be the same finite number regardless of how the bounds approach infinity. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So the story is this integral can be evaluated as different values depending on how fast its limits approaches infinity ? many possible solutions ?

Comment: Correct.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of the [Improper Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Convergence_of_the_integral) is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx&\equiv\lim_{L^{-}\to -\infty}\,\,\lim_{L^{+}\to \infty}\int_{L^{-}}^{L^{+}}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L^{-}\to -\infty}\,\,\lim_{L^{+}\to \infty} \frac12 \log\left(\frac{(L^{+})^2+1}{(L^{-})^2+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

where the integral is defined by taking two separate limits.  Inasmuch as this limit does not exist, the integral is undefined.

However, if  we interpret the integral as a [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), then the upper and lower limits are identical and we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx&\equiv\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac12 \log\left(\frac{L^2+1}{L^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cauchy principal value, even I read about it today some articles. So is there One?None? or many solutions for this integral depending on determining the upper and lower limit of integral ? and can you suggest "Simple" and "Intuitive" book or article talking about CPV please? thanks a lot

Comment: @mohamedmostafa I embedded a link to an article on the CPV.  The answer is that the integral is undefined ... Unless one specifies an alternative interpretation of the integral.  The CPV interpretation is a common that is used pervasively in applications, including evaluation of integrals via contour integration in the complex plane.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that, **if** the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2} \tag1
$$ **does exist**, **then** we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{c\to\infty} \int_{-c}^{+c} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}. \tag2
$$ You have to first prove that the integral in $(1)$ exists to deduce $(2)$.

Think about the following analog situation, you can **not** assert that
$$
(-1)^{\infty}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^{2n}=1. \tag3
$$
One may recall that

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{a \to -\infty}\int_a^c \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}+\lim_{b \to +\infty}\int_c^b \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2},\quad \text{for }\color{red}{\text{any }}c \in \mathbb{R}.
> $$

Comment: Your final statement, "One may recall${}\,\ldots$" is incorrect.  See my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't see any contradiction between what you wrote and my boxed text above.

Comment: The point is that $\lim\limits_{a\to-\infty,\, b\to\infty}$ is not a well defined thing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy "... is not well defined thing.": so it is difficult to say it "is incorrect" :) Do you prefer $\lim_{a \to -\infty} \lim_{b \to +\infty}$ instead?

Comment: If it were $\lim\limits_{a \to -\infty} \lim\limits_{b \to +\infty}$ then it would be $+\infty$ and if it were $\lim\limits_{b \to +\infty} \lim\limits_{a \to -\infty}$ then it would be $-\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Please, how do you define $
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}$? Thanks.

Comment: I don't.  But I know how to define the Cauchy principal value and the values of various limits as the bounds approach $\infty$ in various ways. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To be clear: $\displaystyle \lim_{a\to\,-\infty}\left( \lim_{b\to\,+\infty} \int_a^b \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2} \right)$ $\displaystyle = \lim_{a\to\,-\infty} \Big( +\infty \Big)$ $=+\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think I know that... But I don't really see the point with what I wrote in my answer. You are telling me that the integral does not exist, which is something I first pointed out...

Comment: You say "One may recall that${}\,\ldots$" and then say the integral is equal to a certain limit, but in fact it is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm not sure to understand the point. I have a question, please what does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2} $ means to you?

Comment: It's an indeterminate form.  By letting the bounds approach $\pm\infty$ in various different ways, one can make it approach anything in the closed interval $[-\infty,+\infty]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy So you take two limits (of both bounds) and see if they exist. If you write it down with mathematical symbols, you are not so far from the shortcut $\lim\limits_{a\to-\infty,\, b\to\infty}$. But I think a more rigourous way is to consider the form $\lim\limits_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^c \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}+\lim\limits_{b\to+\infty}\int_c^b \frac{x \, dx}{1+x^2}$, for *any* $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^c\frac {x\,dx}{1+x^2} \vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$ is equal to $-\infty$ no matter what number $c$ is, and the other limit you give is always $+\infty$.  There's nothing more rigorous about what you suggest than about anything else that's been said here. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So, to understand your answer. What you mean is there is no solution for this integral ( Diverge ) or there are many "possible" solutions depends on assumption of same upper and lower limit (c) or different ?!

Comment: @MohamedMostafa Yes, **your integral is divergent**. This is the usual sense. Now there exist some technics of regularization. The principal Cauchy value is just one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{-c}^{2c} \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2} = \frac 1 2 \log\frac{1+4c^2}{1+c^2} \to \frac 1 2 \log 4 \ne 0 \text{ as }c\to\infty.
$$

As always with conditionally convergent things, the limit depends on how the bounds approach $\infty$.